# Select option value not coming in jquery

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a HTML `select` as below:

```
<select name="customer_id">
<option value="5">A1</option>
<option value="7">A2</option>
<option value="3">A3</option>
<option value="6">A4</option>
<option value="4">A5</option>
<option value="2">Root</option>
</select>

<button name="View" type="button" id="view" >View Commission</button>`
```

And I have a jquery as below:

```
$("#view").click(function(){
    var customer_id = $("#customer_id").val();

    alert(customer_id);
});
```

But instead of getting the `customer_id` 's , I am getting alert as `undefined` ! Whats wrong?

View the code : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrcNL/)

Comment: @ArunKillu: He's getting the alert tho...

Comment: Can you replicate this in a fiddle?

Comment: oh ok so thats not the problem

Comment: Also interesting but not really related : http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#customer_id").val();` refers to an element with an ID of customer_id, you only have a name.

Change your select to:

```
<select name="customer_id" id="customer_id">
```

or your selector to:

```
$('select[name="customer_id"]').val();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/y35cA/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using

```
var customer_id = $("#customer_id").val();
```

here $("#customer_id") will work only if select ID is "customer_id"

so  use your select as

```
select id="customer_id" name="customer_id"
```

it will work reply if its work for you.